# Error al usar interfaces en PHP

Tags: php, poo

Muy buenas,

Como ejercicio estoy intentando crear una interface que hereda de otra. Al implementarla en la clase me está dando el error de que los métodos de la clase no son compatibles con los de la interface.

no entiendo por qué, alguien sabría explicárlo?

Gracias

```
    <?php

interface Auto{
    function encender();
    function apagar();
}

interface Gasolina extends Auto{
    function vaciarTanque();
    function llenarTanque($x);
}

class Deportivo implements Gasolina{
    private $tanque = 0;
    private $estado = 'apagado';

    function llenarTanque($x){
        if($x > 50){
            echo $this->tanque = 50;
        }else{
            echo $this->tanque = $x;
        }
    }

    function vaciarTanque(){
        $this->tanque = 0;
    }

    function encender(){
        echo $this->estado = 'encendido';
    }

    function apagar(){
        echo $this->estado = 'apagado';
    }

    function get_estado(){
        return $this->estado;
    }

    function usarCoche($km){
        if($this->tanque == 0){
            echo 'El depósito está vacío, por favor, recárguelo';
        }else{
            if($this->estado == 'apagado'){
                echo 'El coche está apagado';
            }else{
                $kms = $this->tanque * 7;
                if($km > $kms){
                    echo 'No puedes hacer esa cantidad de kms';
                }else{
                    $resto = $kms - $km;
                    if($resto == 0){
                        $this->tanque = $resto / 7;
                        echo "has logrado hacer $km kms, Su tanque está en 0. Por favor. Rellene su tanque";
                    }else{
                        echo "Has logrado hacer $km kms, y le quedan $this->tanque lts en el depósito";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    function secuencia(){
        llenarTanque(35);
        echo get_estado();
        encender();
        echo get_estado();
        usarCoche(100);
        echo get_estado();
        apagar();

    }

}

$coche = new Deportivo;
$coche->secuencia();
```

Comment: El metodo llenarTanque no usa parámetros, sin embargo, al implementarlo estás usando parámetros... Podría ser ese un problema ya que te faltaría implementar el método llenarTanque() sin parámetros.

Comment: Al cambiarlo dice que no está definida la función

Comment: Con lo que dice @lfpp debería corregirse. Aunque tampoco se entiende el sentido de tu función `secuencia`  ¿? ¿Por qué no usas `$this` ahí?

Comment: Disculparme, mi error estaba en lo que comentaba @lfpp y además, en la función de secuencia, no hacía referencia al objeto. Es decir, no incluía $this->llenarTanque, etc etc.     Con el método secuencia buscaba hacer una secuencia preconfigurada como: llenar, encender, usar, apagar         . Muchas Gracias de todos modos

Comment: @lfpp sugiero que escribas una respuesta con la solución. Àlvaro, la cosa es que no le veo sentido al método secuencia, excepto que en tu modelo **todos** los coches deportivos tengan que **ser llenados con `35`** y seguir **siempre** esa secuencia.

Comment: Sería bueno revises la [doc. oficial sobre interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.interfaces.php), para que te familiarices con la estructura

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya lo he pasado a una respuesta. Gracias por avisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo llenarTanque no usa parámetros, sin embargo, al implementarlo estás usando parámetros. Se puede solucionar añadiendo un parámetro al método de la interfaz o quitándolo de la implementación

Además, tal y como indica  @A. Cedano en comentarios, debes usar el $this-> en las llamadas que realizas en el método secuencia().

Tu código puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
 <?php

interface Auto{
    function encender();
    function apagar();
}

interface Gasolina extends Auto{
    function vaciarTanque();
    function llenarTanque($x);
}

class Deportivo implements Gasolina{
    private $tanque = 0;
    private $estado = 'apagado';

    function llenarTanque($x){
        if($x > 50){
            echo $this->tanque = 50;
        }else{
            echo $this->tanque = $x;
        }
    }

    function vaciarTanque(){
        $this->tanque = 0;
    }

    function encender(){
        echo $this->estado = 'encendido';
    }

    function apagar(){
        echo $this->estado = 'apagado';
    }

    function get_estado(){
        return $this->estado;
    }

    function usarCoche($km){
        if($this->tanque == 0){
            echo 'El depósito está vacío, por favor, recárguelo';
        }else{
            if($this->estado == 'apagado'){
                echo 'El coche está apagado';
            }else{
                $kms = $this->tanque * 7;
                if($km > $kms){
                    echo 'No puedes hacer esa cantidad de kms';
                }else{
                    $resto = $kms - $km;
                    if($resto == 0){
                        $this->tanque = $resto / 7;
                        echo "has logrado hacer $km kms, Su tanque está en 0. Por favor. Rellene su tanque";
                    }else{
                        echo "Has logrado hacer $km kms, y le quedan $this->tanque lts en el depósito";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    function secuencia(){
        $this->llenarTanque(35);
        echo $this->get_estado();
        $this->encender();
        echo $this->get_estado();
        $this->usarCoche(100);
        echo $this->get_estado();
        $this->apagar();

    }

}

$coche = new Deportivo;
$coche->secuencia();
```